# Java's ParseException

Tags: java, parsing, parseexception

I've been investigating Java's [`ParseException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/ParseException.html), when trying to write my own method that parses from a `String` to an `int`, and have two questions:

1. When should I throw it? Java's `Integer.parseInt(String string)` throws a `NumberFormatException` when an invalid input is given (makes sense with it being a subclass of `IllegalArgumentException`), and does not throw `ParseException` at all.
2. What is "`errorOffset`"? `ParseException`'s constructor forces you to give it a value - what does it mean?

Comment: For the second question, the `getErrorOffset` method tells you what it's for. It's "the position where the error was found."

Comment: What does that mean though? The position the error was found in the String? Or the method? Is a ParseException then caused by some error (eg a letter) in the String?

Comment: I interpret it as the position in the `String`. Telling a position in the method wouldn't be very useful information to most callers, since the details of the implementation shouldn't matter.

Comment: In the string. Parsing `"987A65"` would show error offset at index `3`.

Comment: That's true, thanks. Does that answer the first question then? `ParseException` should be thrown when there is a problem in the String? Then is it preferable to throw `ParseException` or `NumberFormatException`?

Comment: NumberFormatException should be thrown. ParseException is usually when conversion between type format. You usually saw parseException when you try parse a date.

Answer (score 1):

Throwing a `ParseException` for a `parseXYZ()` method (that actually parses something) is perfectly valid. `Integer.parseInt` throws a `NumberFormatException` since it is a subtype of `RuntimeException` and therefore does not force you to surround it with try-catch (This is not true for `ParseException`).

The `offset` field is used to identify the position for which the error occurred. With that information, you may be able to use whatever partial data you already parsed.